# Counter-example: $W$ subspace satisfying $W = \bigoplus_{i\in I} (W\cap V_j) $ that is not T-invariant

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V_1,...,V_m$ be the T-primary subspaces of $V$. Give an example of a subspace $W$ satisfying $W = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{m} (W\cap V_j) $ that is not T-invariant

Can someone help finding an example for this? I was thinking about taking a decomposition made of a chain: $V = \mbox{ker} (t-\lambda)^2\oplus \mbox{ker}(t-\lambda)$ and then take a vector in $\mbox{ker}(t-\lambda)$, a vector in $\mbox{ker} (t-\lambda)^2$ that is not in the first one and take $W$ as their span, but not much progress...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V = \mathbb{R^2}$ and if $\alpha$ denotes canonical basis, let:

$[T]^{\alpha}_{\alpha} =  A = \begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 0     \\
    1       & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$

We note that $A^2=0$, so $m_T=t^2$ and $V = V_{t^2}$. Take $W = [e_1]$. Clearly we have that $e_1\in V_{t^2}$ and therefore satisfies $W = W\cap V_{t^2}$ as a unique direct sum. But instead $T(e_1) = e_2\notin W$, since $e_2$ and $e_1$ are linearly independent. This shows that $W$ is not T-invariant.